# VBA convert textbox entry to an integer

Tags: vba

I am trying to convert a textbox entry to an integer:

```
 Dim cplayers() As Variant: cplayers = Array ("Danny", "Freddy", "Billy", "Tommy")
 Dim i As Integer
 i = CInt(TextBox3)
 MsgBox (cplayers(i) & " is on first base.")
```

When I run it now, the message box always reads "Danny is on first base." so it must be reading the textbox as empty and assuming the entry is 0 then. What should I change?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to (or debut.print) see what value i is before being passed into your array?

Comment: I just tried that and the value of i is showing as 0 although the value in the textbox is 3. So the textbox isn't being read correctly for some reason.

Comment: Try to qualify the text box. Thisworkbook.sheets(“?”).TextBox3

Comment: Or is this from a user form?

Comment: Not sure what a user form is. I ran the line i = CInt(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Textbox3) and got an error that said "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Try adding that but textbox3.value

Comment: Comes back with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ActiveX Text Box to import the value.

> **To Insert:** Developer Tab > Insert > ActiveX Controls > Text Box (ActiveX Control)

You can then extract your value as such:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim cplayers() As Variant: cplayers = Array("Danny", "Freddy", "Billy", "Tommy")
Dim i As Integer

i = TextBox1.Value
MsgBox cplayers(i) & " is on first base."

End Sub
```

You could also refer to the object but that would be overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

The field that holds the actual entry for the Textbox seems to be "TextBox3.text"

```
Dim cplayers() As Variant: cplayers = Array ("Danny", "Freddy", "Billy", "Tommy")
Dim i As Integer
i = CInt(TextBox3.text)
MsgBox (cplayers(i) & " is on first base.")
```

There is also a check that can help you to prevent wrong inputs in the calculations. You can use `isNumeric()` to determine if the entered value is a valid number like `If IsNumeric(TextBox3.text) Then`

Comment: When I enter TextBox3.text I get an error that says object required. 
     MsgBox(IsNumeric(TextBox3)) returned True.